# JavaScript reading reading list of form items

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, loops

I have a form with multiple input fields:

```
<input name="a1"/>
<input name="a2"/>
<input name="a3"/>
```

All field names are the same with an added digit.

I need JavaScript to read these values into an array.

```
for i = 1 to 3
   a(i) = form(i)
next
```

Complete code:

```
var listC = [ "C", "A", "B" ]; 
a1 = form.a1.value; 
a2 = form.a2.value;
a3 = form.a3.value; 

if (listC[0] == a1.toUpperCase()) {
    NumCorrect = NumCorrect + 1
}
if (listC[1] == a2.toUpperCase()) {
    NumCorrect = NumCorrect + 1
}
if (listC[2] == a3.toUpperCase()) {
    NumCorrect = NumCorrect + 1
} 

<input type="text" size="2" name="a1" size="2"/>
<input type="text" size="2" name="a2" size="2"/>
<input type="text" size="2" name="a3" size="2"/>
```

Comment: Post the HTML structure.

Comment: Can you include the relevant `HTML` and show what you have tried so far please? Thank you.

Comment: var listC = [
    "C",
    "A",
    "B"
];
    a1 = form.a1.value;
    a2 = form.a2.value;
    a3 = form.a3.value;
    if (listC[0] == a1.toUpperCase()) {NumCorrect = NumCorrect + 1}
    if (listC[1] == a2.toUpperCase()) {NumCorrect = NumCorrect + 1}
    if (listC[2] == a3.toUpperCase()) {NumCorrect = NumCorrect + 1}
<input type="text" size="2" name="a1" size="2"/>
<input type="text" size="2" name="a2" size="2"/>
<input type="text" size="2" name="a3" size="2"/>

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to post so that it can be read?

Comment: var arr=[]; for(i=1;i<4;i++){ arr[i]=document.getElementById('a'+i).value;} console.log(arr); try this note i has written on my phone hence please be careful syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you're after.

```js
var a = [],
    inputs = document.querySelectorAll('[name^="a"]');

[].forEach.call(inputs, function(input){
    a.push(input.value);
});

console.log(a);
```

```html
<input name="a1" value="a111"/>
<input name="a2" value="a222"/>
<input name="a3" value="a333"/>
```

Comment: wont it also select `name="abc"`?

Comment: @11thdimension, it would but that OP's structure.

Comment: OP's format is `a` forllowed by a number, not anything

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding 'id' attribute similarly 'name' Like,

**HTML**

```
<input id="name1" name="name1">  
<input id="name2" name="name2">
```

**Javascript**

```
var formData = [];

for(var i=1 ; i<length; i++){
   formData.push($('#name'+i).val());
}
```

Comment: Questions without jQuery tag should be answered in vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the form structure you could retrieve it with vanilla javascript as follows:

```
var arr = [];

var currentElementIndex = 1;
while(document.getElementsByName('a'+currentElementIndex)) {
  arr.push(document.getElementsByName('a'+currentElementIndex).value);
  currentElementIndex++;
}
```

Assuming id's are >= 1 and sequential.